# Kotlin - removing an element from list inside when and let

Tags: kotlin

I found that removing an item from a list in kotlin inside `when` which is placed inside `let` requires adding an `else` branch and I don't understand why is it required.
Can anyone explain?

Please see the following examples.

There is a nullable list

```
val list = mutableListOf<Int?>(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

and I would like to remove an element from the list after a null check.
The implementation using `let` and `when` requires the `else` branch.

```
fun `remove element inside let and when`(random: Int) {
    list[random]?.let {
        when {
            it > 4 -> list.remove(it)
            else -> { //else branch required
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I use an element from a list inside `when` but without `let` the `else` branch is not required

```
fun `remove element inside when`(random: Int) {
    when {
        random > 4 -> list.remove(random)
        //no else branch required
    }
}
```

When `if` is used instead of `when` in `let` the `else` branch is also not required

```
fun `remove element inside let and if `(random: Int) {
    list[random]?.let {
        if (it > 4) {
            list.remove(it)
        } //no else required
    }
}
```

Finally, when the operation is an assignment inside `when` the `else` branch is also not required

```
fun `modify element inside let and when`(random: Int) {
    list[random]?.let {
        when {
            it > 4 -> list[random] = 10
            //no else branch required
        }
    }
}
```

It was tested with kotlin version 1.3.72.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`let` returns a value, even if you don't use it.

Now by default kotlin takes the last statement as the return value.
Therefore the value of the `when` expression is used as return value.
And this in turn forces the `when` to be exaustive.

You can observe the same behavior if you just try to assign a `when` to some value.

```
val foo = when {
            it > 4 -> list.remove(it)
            else -> { //else branch required
            }
          }
```

In your case since you don't need a result you could use `also`